# Omni-Channel Lead Transfer Event

Tags: lightning, omnichannel

How can I capture the Omni-Channel 'Transfer' event? We need to do some custom post-processing or pre-processing when a Lead is transferred to another agent.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the Transfer event, you have to write trigger on AgetWork and you have to check for status field. Status field value change in following ways.

If a work item is assigned to agent and it is in new item then status field will be Assigned.
If a work item is accepted by agent and then status will be opened.
If a work item is transferred by agent and then agent work status will be transfer.

Please go through the below link for more information on agent work object.
[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_agentwork.htm][1]